# What advantages are there having a web site per web service versus per application in IIS?

Tags: web-services, iis-7

What advantages are there having a web site per web service versus an application per webservice in IIS7?

As far as I can see there is no advantage apart from being able to stop/start a single service when it is a website. It doesn't look like this is achievable with applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web sites can have different bindings and host headers.  With applications -- you can still stop/start single services via their Application Pools. You can also take advantage of configuration inheritance if you use applications.